# Set title Cakephp 2.x

Tags: title, cakephp-2.6

I am trying to change the title of a page. 
The default.ctp view has the following code:

```
<title>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('title'); ?>
     - Welcome
</title>
```

I'm trying to use the following code in the controller of the page:

```
$title = 'Overview';
$this->set('title');
```

But unfortunately I do not see see 'Overview - Welcome', but only the name of the function of the controller followed by ' - Welcome'.
Can anyone help me to find the problem why it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if    `$this->set('title')` will work

I usually use the 'compact' function to set the variables as they're named.

Like this: `$this->set(compact('title'));` or just simply this `$this->set('title', $title);`

Comment: `$this->set('title')` would work only if you do `echo $title;` in the view. `$this->fetch('title')` will return it's default value, something like path to the view ctp, in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can define what `$this->fetch('title')` returns using **`View::assign()`** function that sets block's value this way:

```
$this->assign('title', $title);
```

See more in the documentation about [view blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#extending-views).

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of:

```php
$this->set('title');
```

you must use:

```php
$this->set('title', $title);
```